# In DFP, how do I set a banner keep displaying until the impression is finished running?

Tags: advertising, google-dfp, impressions, ad-server

I using DFP.
[image]
I have one banner that impression set as 500,000 impressions, however the banner will sometimes show Google Adsense ads while the impression count is not reached yet.

How do I set the banner keep displaying the banner that I uploaded until the impression is finished running?

Update Question:
My Deliver Impressions was set as "As Fast as possible" but sometimes it still showing other google ads.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You want to deliver the impressions "as fast as possible" from under the "Adjust delivery", "Deliver impressions" drop down.

[image]

"As fast as possible" delivers the impressions first (before AdSense) where as evenly will intermix them and frontloaded will show *mostly* your banner.

[Here is the Google support page about delivery speed](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/177291?hl=en) where this is documented.

Comment: The deliver impressions was set to as fast as possible but problem same.